# Altering the shape of a Gaussian curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, coordinate-systems

I just posted this on Stack Overflow but then I found out about this forum. I hope I'm not breaking any policies by posting the same question here. I am not allowed to post images here yet, so please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567096/merging-a-straight-line-into-a-gaussian-curve

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should post a link to this question at stackoverflow, so people there will know it has been posted here.